# Objective interpretation of a parameter

Tags: parameterization

In the following model equation (purely statistical / descriptive model, no mechanistic information involved):

$$ Y = a \times X^b $$

considering that $Y$ and $X$ are two measurements, say, $Y$ is temperature and $X$ is air moisture, and $a$ and $b$ are two parameters (to be estimated).

What would be the most objective interpretation of $a$ and $b$ ?

Is saying that parameter $a$ is the value of $Y$ when $X = 1$, and parameter $b$ is the nonlinear effect of $X$ on $Y$, correct ?

Comment: The most objective definition is already given by the formula. I suspect you are interested in interpretation of the parameters?

Comment: You are right. I would like to interpret these two parameter in the most objective way, because I feel / think what I propose in the last sentence is not the best I can say about them.

Comment: In order to make any interpretation, we need to know what $Y$ and $X$ represent. But there is an ambiguity present in the question: do you intend these variables to be the *theoretical* constructs thought of as "actual" temperature and "actual" moisture content, or do they represent *measurements* of these things?  A "purely statistical" model would often be understood as the former whereas a "purely descriptive" model would likely be understood as the latter, but you are calling it both!

Comment: @whuber by "statistical / descriptive" I mean that I have measurements of both X and Y, and the model equation is just some equation that fits well. a and b have no ground in real processes. However I still want to give names to them...

Comment: That's a useful clarification, thank you.  Please note that it means [the answer you have accepted](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/152836/919) cannot be considered entirely valid, because it makes no mention of the crucial distinction between a value and a measurement of that value, nor does it recognize that your model is merely a fit to data.

Comment: @whuber Even though I don't quite understant how this new piece of information can help improve the answer, I hope Askakal will know, and will use it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [drag force equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drag_%28physics%29) in physics: $$F_D=av^2$$
Here, $v$ is the speed of an object, and $a=1/2\rho C_DA$ and $b=2$. Air density is $\rho$, the $C_D$ is a drag coefficient and $A$ is the surface of an object.

You say that the drag is proportional to the square of the speed and the surface area of the object. As you see there's no standard way to express this relationship, other than saying that it's *proportional* to this or that.

Another example is Cobb-Douglas production function from microeconomics: $$Y=AL^\beta K^\alpha$$
Here, $A$ - total factor productivity, and $\alpha,\beta$ - output elstaicities of labor and capital. As you see the $b$ coefficient was given a specific name which is interpretable in its domain, not some generic "nonlinearity" term.

Comment: In the drag force equation, parameter $a$ is short for 1/2*rho*Cd. In my case, there is no such information about any of the two parameters I wish to descripe / interpret.

Comment: My question actually finds its roots in the fact that it is common for people in my work to try to interpret things, especially parameters, even if that may not be appropriate. Your answer seems to suggest it is not appropriate in my case. Am I right ?

Comment: You have to interpret, of course. It's just there's no *standard* way to call these things. For instance, see how they attributed $a$ to the area and the air density, and called the remaining "drag coefficient", they don't have the name for the $b$. Similarly, you can call your $a$ "coefficient of moisture temperature".

Comment: OK I agree one can call $a$ the "moisture coefficient", then how do I call $b$ ? maybe $a$ = "moisture linear coef." and $b$ = "moisture nonlinear coef." ? I understand this is very open...

Comment: @Rodolphe, I gave you another example in the update.

Comment: OK. Actually I thought there was (maybe, I was looking for) some formal / objective / domain independent way of giving a name to these coefficients. Maybe there is not, as the two examples you provided seem to imply. This is an acceptable answer in my opinion.